# How do I use configure.ac to include the contents of AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT?

Tags: c, header-files, autotools, autoconf, automake

`AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT` is a macro that expands to a bunch of standard header files, plus related `autoconf`-generated checks.  In fact, the docs says it expands to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
# include <sys/types.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
# include <sys/stat.h>
#endif
#ifdef STDC_HEADERS
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stddef.h>
#else
# ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
#  include <stdlib.h>
# endif
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
# if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
#  include <memory.h>
# endif
# include <string.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
# include <strings.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
# include <inttypes.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
# include <stdint.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
# include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

**How can I use `configure.ac` to include the contents of `AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT` in my `config.h`?**

Comment: Do you mean config.h?

Comment: AFAIK it is auto generated. I always get them into config.h in my projects. Did you launch a reconfiguration of autotool project. If you are into Eclipse right click on project and select _reconfigure project_

Comment: Yes, I know `config.h` is auto-generated.  I'm asking about how to put a particular thing inside of it.

Comment: I meant that AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT are always added into config.h in my case. On monday I'll look at my projects and I'll give you a feefback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT` is for use by autoconf check macros.  It doesn't output anything you can use directly in your project.

That list seems mildly obsolete to me.  It doesn't seem too likely that there are any systems providing `<strings.h>` but not `<string.h>` any more.  I think it is better, in general, to check for what you actually use; and even beyond that, only for what you have found in practice to be non-portable to the platforms you care about.